# C++ cannot call set_value for promise move-captured in a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, std-future

I'm trying to write a fairly simple method that returns a future. A lambda sets the future. This is a minimal example. In reality the lambda might be invoked in a different thread, etc.

```cpp
#include <future>

std::future<std::error_code> do_something() {
  std::promise<std::error_code> p;
  auto fut = p.get_future();
  auto lambda = [p = std::move(p)] {
    std::error_code error;
    p.set_value(error);
  };
  lambda();
  return std::move(fut);
}

int main() { return do_something().get().value(); }
```

For some reason I get a type error. VSCode intellisense says:

> no instance of overloaded function "`std::promise<_Ty>::set_value [with _Ty=std::error_code]`" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match) -- argument types are: (`std::remove_reference_t<std::error_code &>`) -- object type is: `const std::remove_reference_t<std::promise<std::error_code> &>`

And MSVC compiler says:

> error C2663: '`std::promise<std::error_code>::set_value`': 2 overloads have no legal conversion for '`this`' pointer

I really don't understand the VS Code error. Is it saying that it thinks `error` is a `const promise<error_code>`? How do I correctly call `set_value` on a promise which was `move`d inside a lambda's capture?

Comment: Just add `mutable` keyword to lambda, `[...](...) mutable { ... }`. Mutable keyword allows to modify captured values.

Comment: If `mutable` keywoard is not supported, I don't remember if C++11 supports it, then do following `[...  p = std::make_shared<ClassName>(std::move(p)) ...](...) { ... }` - in other words wrap your value into [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), because constant shared pointer allows to modify its underlying object. Also you can use `std::unique_ptr` instead of shared. If you wrap into shared pointer then don't forget inside lambda body to use it as a pointer, i.e. dereference it through `->` like `p->SomeMethod();`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Arty. If you make an answer I'll mark it!

Comment: Great! Wait 5 minutes and I'll create an answer.

Comment: I created an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70023348/941531), you may Accept and/or UpVote it. Thanks for interesting Question!

Comment: @Arty c++11 had mutable lambdas, and OP is move-capturing (c++14)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default lambda stores all its captured values (non-references) as `const` values, you can't modify them. But lambda supports keyword `mutable`, you can add it like this:

`[/*...*/](/*...*/) mutable { /*...*/ }`

This will allow inside body of a lambda to modify all its values.

If for some reason you can't use `mutable`, then you can use other work-around:

`[/*...*/, p = std::make_shared<ClassName>(std::move(p)), /* ... */](/*...*/) {/*...*/}`

In other words wrap your moved value into [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), you can also use [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) if you like.

Wrapping into shared pointer solves the problem, because shared pointer (unique also) allows to modify its underlying object value even if pointer itself is `const`.

Don't forget inside the body of a lambda to dereference `p` as a pointer, in other words if you used `p.SomeMethod()`, now you have to use `p->SomeMethod()` (with `->` operator).